# Google Tag Manager: Tracking funnel event completion on a single page application

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I have an eCommerce-like website set up in the following [hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7usp.png). We currently use Google Tag Manager (GTM) and Google Analytics (GA) as part of our web analytics stack.

Currently, each product has its own sign-up page where a potential customer has to go through 4 steps (Quote > Select Plan > Application Details > Review and Pay). The sign-up pages are single application pages (SPA), with static URLs that do not change.

Essentially, [clicking the "next" button causes the page to dynamically load assets for the next step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agy48.png).

The goal is to be able to track at which stage customers usually drop off during the sign-up process. In such a scenario, what kind of options are there available to track the "completion" of each sign-up step? Based on my understanding, I believe that some of the solutions include using virtual pageviews or tracking button clicks on the SPA as custom events.

What would be the most efficient implementation that allows integration with Google Analytics to track the funnel completion on the sign-up page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual pageview so you can then configure a funnel in Analytics on these.

A solution for GTM could be to create a different trigger for each step of the funnel that is activated by clicking on the buttons. These trigger fire a pageview tag to Analytics with the **page** parameter (in Field to set) different contextually based on the step (i.e. /step-1, /step-2, ...).

Comment: I suppose a click trigger (e.g. defining the condition as Click ID = button id) makes sense and would likely work. What if my button has no static button id? i.e. the button id is not fixed and dynamically changes when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Need to use other reference/attribute about that button like class or refer to father DOM reference.